# Extjs4 loading image message

Tags: load, extjs4

I have build a small app with extjs4 using MVC architecture. When user login first time the application needs 5-10 secs to load. How do I place a loading image that will inform user to wait while app is initializing? (like shencha's please wait image while examples page is loading)

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 2):

To do this, I have added a variable `Ext.LoadMask` in my controller like this :

```
var loginMask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getBody(), {msg:"Please wait ..."});
```

then, before calling function that call the server side (using AJAX) for authentication I call the show function like this :

`loginMask.show();`

after that, I mean after the server response I call :

`loginMask.hide();`

and this is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Loadmask might be what you need http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.LoadMask

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use a modal MessageBox to achieve the same:

```
        Ext.MessageBox.show({
            title: 'Please wait',
            msg: 'Loading...',
            progressText: 'Loading...',
            width:300,
            wait: true,
            waitConfig: {interval: 200},
            progress:true,
            closable:false,
            modal: true
    });
```

When done, simple call the following:

```
Ext.MessageBox.hide();
```